# How to build video manager with Unity Addressable Assets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, 360-virtual-reality, oculusgo, oculusquest

I am working on a project where users can watch 360 videos on the Oculus GO, the problem is the file is too big since the videos are higher quality. The best solution I found is Asset Bundles or Addressable Assets. I got the addressable assets to load and play but the problem is I have more than more so I would need to build a video manager or something so I can make each button play its own video. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, On your menubar, you can set button click listers which will load that asset bundle.